# @PersistenceUnit EntityManagerFactory use incorrect database (sun-appserv-samples)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I use Java and hibernate 4.3.

If I create a factory manually:

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Chat");
```

All is ok. JPA use database specified in persistence.xml.

But if I get EntityManagerFactory via injection:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "Chat")
private EntityManagerFactory factory;
```

JPA create and use sun-appserv-samples database. Why?

Incidentally, in EntityManagerFactory.getProperties(), key javax.persistence.jdbc.url == my correct database. But this propery is ignored.

Demo project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55489242/JPATest.zip

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Chat" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/chat_db"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />        
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="2" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="250" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you injecting the entityManager via Spring or something? If so can you post the code snippet?

Comment: I use JavaEE + hibernate. I rewrote post and added demo project.

Answer (score 0):

in the bundle (JPATest.zip) you have provided you execute your DAO either as test (MyTest.java) or as application code (as web application). I think that on the 2nd case your application doesn't find the persistence.xml and therefore it uses the default NetBeans db. In order to resolve this make sure that persistence.xml is located in META-INF and that the latter is located in the classpath.

By the way I would recommend you using maven to build the project and its standard project folder layout (hierarchy). In this case you could place the persistence.xml in the path src/main/resources/persistence.xml.

Comment: I wrote:
Incidentally, in EntityManagerFactory.getProperties(), key javax.persistence.jdbc.url == my correct database.
persistence.xml is loaded. javax.persistence.jdbc.url is correct. But JPA use other database.